# How to install turicreate in mac

Tags: turi-create

When i try to install **turicreate** in my mac machine its showing the following error:

Collecting turicreate
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/turicreate/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping

**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement turicreate (from versions: )**

**No matching distribution found for turicreate**

please help me to resolve it?

Comment: What mac os version do you have? Please read the official installation docs at 
https://github.com/apple/turicreate

Comment: Are you installing it on venv (virtual environment)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a Python version mismatch. At the moment TuriCreate supports only 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6.

Here is more on setting up Python environment for popular ML packages on Mac -
[Machine Learning Compass](https://medium.com/@maxim.volgin/machine-learning-compass-fcee3d9ac3b3)